# Show $ (\ln\ln(x) )(\ln x )+\ln\ln\ln x=o_{+\infty} (\ln x )^{2}+\ln\ln\ln\ln x $

Tags: asymptotics

I would like to show that 
$$  (\ln\ln(x) )(\ln x )+\ln\ln\ln x=o_{+\infty} (\ln x )^{2}+\ln\ln\ln\ln x $$

by using these methods :

- limit   $$\lim_{x\to +\infty }\dfrac{ (\ln\ln(x) )(\ln x )+\ln\ln\ln x }{  (\ln x )^{2}+\ln\ln\ln\ln x }$$
- properties of symbol o  $$  \ln x = o(x) $$
  [image]

[image]

$$\dfrac{ (\ln\ln(x) )(\ln x )+\ln\ln\ln x }{  (\ln x )^{2}+\ln\ln\ln\ln x }=\dfrac{\ln\ln x +\dfrac{ \ln\ln\ln x }{  \ln x }     }{    \ln x +\dfrac{  \ln\ln\ln\ln x      }{  \ln x  }  }  $$
 in this last expression how can i use $   \lim_{   x\to +\infty  }\dfrac{ \ln x }{x} =0$

Comment: What did the drowning number theorist say? "log log log log log log log"

Comment: yes this helps to see why the limit goes to 0 thanks, but could we use second method which means properties of small o as first photo shows

Answer (score 1):

Hint. By letting $x=\ln(t)$, 
$$\lim_{   x\to +\infty  }\dfrac{ \ln x }{x} =0\implies \lim_{   t\to +\infty  }\dfrac{ \ln(\ln t) }{\ln(t)}=0.$$
Hence your limit is
$$\lim_{   x\to +\infty  }\dfrac{\frac{\ln\ln x}{\ln x} +\dfrac{ \ln\ln\ln x }{  (\ln x)^2 }     }{ 1 +\dfrac{  \ln\ln\ln\ln x      }{  (\ln x)^2 }  }=0$$

Comment: could you elaborate

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: By taking hint from @Did $$\ln\ln\ln\ln x\ll\ln\ln\ln x\ll\ln\ln x\ll\ln x\ll(\ln x)^2 $$I can  see ur way Thank you